# Finger Scrolling in QGraphicsView in QT?

Tags: qt

I want to know whether by default QgraphicsView provides finger scrolling in case of Touch Screen devices or we need to have our own kineticscroller class to achieve it.

I want to have one QListWidget which will have some custom contols added to it and i am adding that list to scene and scene to graphicsview now i want to have finger scroller, whether graphics view will have this property by default ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt provides the [`QGesture`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qgesture.html) class for handling gesture events. You can inherit from this class and create any gesture you want or use one of the predefined gestures like `QPanGesture`, `QPinchGesture` and `QSwipeGesture`.

Gestures can be enabled for all `QWidgets` and for `QGraphicsScene` which is probably what you want in order to move the items in your `QGraphicsView`. Notice that in most cases you have to explicitly write code about how every gesture will be evaluated.

> Gestures can be enabled for instances of QWidget and QGraphicsObject
>   subclasses.

For an example of gesture programming have a look at the [image gestures example](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/gestures-imagegestures.html). Also have a look at the [Gestures Programming](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/gestures-overview.html) article of Qt docs.

If you want multi-touch support in your application have a look at [this video](http://qt.nokia.com/learning/online/talks/archive/developerdays2009/tech-talks/using-multi-touch-and-gestures-with-qt/) from the 2009 DevDays. You may also want to check the [`QTouchEvent`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qtouchevent.html) class.

Comment: So u mean to say that by default QgraphicsView does not provide finger scrolling i need to add QGesture to support it ?

Comment: Exactly. Finger scrolling is nothing more than a pressed mouse moving, so create the gesture and handle it the way you want