# Qt: How to implement Panning/Zooming in QGraphicsScene with two finger gestures on laptop trackpad (win/mac)?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qgraphicsscene

I have a Qt 6.2 Application (Windows/Mac) using QGraphicsScene and want to use 2 fingers on the touch pad of my laptop for panning - as many other applications do.

Zooming in/out works fine, but using 2 fingers for panning always results in zoom out.

I found a number of questions and some fragmentary samples. But no half way complete example:

- [Finger Scrolling in QGraphicsView in QT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8089838/finger-scrolling-in-qgraphicsview-in-qt)
- https://forum.qt.io/topic/119221/how-to-listen-to-qtouchevent-originating-from-a-precision-touch-pad
- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/gestures-overview.html

What is the right way to do this?

What i tried so far (on Windows):

1)

```
MyGraphicsView::MyGraphicsView(...) : QGraphicsView()
{
    viewport()->setAttribute(Qt::WA_AcceptTouchEvents);

...
bool MyGraphicsView::viewportEvent ( QEvent * event )
{
     switch (event->type())
    {
    case QEvent::TouchBegin:
    case QEvent::TouchUpdate:
    case QEvent::TouchEnd:
        {
        // never called
        }
```

2. 

```
MyDocWin::MyDocWin(...) : CMDIAppDocWin(),
{
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_AcceptTouchEvents);
...
bool MyDocWin::event(QEvent *event)
{
    switch (event->type())
    {
    case QEvent::TouchBegin:
    case QEvent::TouchUpdate:
    case QEvent::TouchEnd:
        {
            // never called
        }
...
```

3. 

```
std::vector<Qt::GestureType> sgGestureTypes = {Qt::TapGesture, Qt::TapAndHoldGesture,Qt::PanGesture       ,Qt::PinchGesture     ,Qt::SwipeGesture         };
    
    
    MyGraphicsView::MyGraphicsView(...) : QGraphicsView()
    {
       for(Qt::GestureType gesture : sgGestureTypes)
            grabGesture(gesture);
    ...
    bool MyGraphicsView::event(QEvent *event)
    {
      switch (event->type())
        {
        case QEvent::Gesture:
        case QEvent::NativeGesture:
                    // never called
```

4. 

```
    MyDocWin::MyDocWin(...) : CMDIAppDocWin(),
    {
    for (Qt::GestureType gesture : sgGestureTypes)
        grabGesture(gesture);
...
    bool MyDocWin::event(QEvent *event)
    {
        switch (event->type())
        {
        case QEvent::Gesture:
        case QEvent::NativeGesture:
                // never called
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally manged to get this work. What i found out:

Pan Gestures (in Qt) are converted to Mouse Wheel messages which can have a y and also a x offset. This seems strange to me, as there is no Mouse with a horizontal Wheel.
Even more confusing, by MS definition Pan events are converted to WM_VSCROLL/WM_HSCROLL events (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wintouch/windows-touch-gestures-overview)

Most of this (i.e panning) is handled quite well by Qt, but not all:

- It seems impossible to distinguish between a gesture event on the track pad and a real wheel event on the mouse. I originally wanted to use the Mouse Wheel always for Zoom AND use the Touch Pads Pan gesture. This combination seems to be impossible. I now use Ctrl/Shift for mouse wheel zoom. This solved the problem

The zoom gesture with two fingers i had to handle differently on Mac and Windows:

- On windows a wheel event is sent with “(event->modifiers() & Qt::ControlModifier) == true”. On the mac not. So i wrote:

  ```
  void myGraphicsView::wheelEvent(QWheelEvent* event)
  {
  if(event->modifiers() & (Qt::ControlModifier | Qt::ShiftModifier))
  myZoomFunction(event, 0);
  else
  QGraphicsView::wheelEvent(event);
  }
  ```
- On MacOs we have to listen to a QEvent::NativeGesture - but thats not called on Windows:

  ```
  bool myGraphicsView::viewportEvent ( QEvent * event )
  {
  switch (event->type())
  {
  case QEvent::NativeGesture:
  auto nge = dynamic_cast<QNativeGestureEvent*>(event);
  if (nge)
  {
  if(nge->gestureType() == Qt::ZoomNativeGesture)
  ```

- On MacOs scrolling up/down is sent in angleDelta().x(), instead of angleDelta().y(). Both values are swapped for any reason.

Comment: Mice do exist with horizontal scroll wheels, for what it's worth. The Logitech MX Master series for example -- they're fairly popular.

Comment: Anyway, with Qt 6 there is `QInputEvent::deviceType()` which returns `::Mouse` or `::TouchPad`, depending on what generated the event. I think you're out of luck with Qt 5 though.

Comment: I wouldn't trust that device type. It says scroll events from my real physical mouse are from a touchpad.